# redux-form: accessing refs in child component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am using [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/) with [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

So inside my redux-form I have a child component of , which returns a **react-select** component. I would simply like to know how I can pass this a reference to this component. I have tried the standard syntax of: -

```
ref={(input) => { this.activityInput = input; }}
```

And also tried that with: -

```
withRef={true}
```

However, all this ever does is return a **ProxyComponent** object when I try to access the reference via this.activityInput in the parent component.

I am totally stumped with this one. I've tried reading the docs and have Googled extensively for an answer but I can't seem to find one and many of the information out there refers to the old ReactJS ref syntax of: -

```
ref="whateveryouwant"
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In case it might help anyone, I solved it like this: -

```
      <Field
        name="activity"
        component={FormFieldActivity}
        ref={input => this.activity = input}
        withRef
      />
```

And I am retrieving the value of the select field using: -

```
this.activity.getRenderedComponent().getValue()
```

Which returns the value from the child component's state: -

```
const handleOnChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({ value });
}

getValue(){
  return this.state.value
}
```

Seems simple enough in the end. I hope that might help someone.

Comment: was the component "FormFieldActivity" receiving the ref?